# Mysql, is possible use outer alias in SUBsubqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Is possible use outer alias in SUBsubqueries?

I Try like this, but getting error, because pf.id is Unknown column.

SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'pf.id' in 'where clause'

````
SELECT
    pf.id planejamentoID,
    ag.data dataAtendimento,
    pr.apelido apelidoDoDentista,
    pr.id profissionalID,
    cl.nome nomeDaClinica,
    pf.status status,
    pf.desconto desconto,
    pf.recibo,
    pf.notaFiscal,
    (
        SELECT count(*) FROM
            (SELECT 
                vencimento, NOW(), vencimento<NOW() as parcela_vencida from planejamentoPagamento pp 
                where planejamento_id = pf.id <--- HERE ( Unknown column )
            ) as c
            WHERE c.parcela_vencida = 1
    ) as parcela_vencida
    
    from planejamentoFinanceiro pf
        join agendamento as ag on pf.agendamento_id = ag.id
        join profissional pr on ag.profissionalID = pr.id
        join clinica cl on ag.clinicaID = cl.id
    where ag.pacienteID = 1000011;
    ```
````

Comment: for that i wished you provided a full [mre] , because usually that works just fine, and i really don't want to produce 5 tables

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed using an `EXIST` clause:

```
SELECT
    pf.id planejamentoID,
    ag.data dataAtendimento,
    pr.apelido apelidoDoDentista,
    pr.id profissionalID,
    cl.nome nomeDaClinica,
    pf.status status,
    pf.desconto desconto,
    pf.recibo,
    pf.notaFiscal,
    (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT vencimento, NOW(), vencimento < NOW() AS parcela_vencida 
                    FROM planejamentoPagamento pp 
                    WHERE planejamento_id = pf.id AND vencimento < NOW() = 1)) AS parcela_vencida
FROM
    planejamentoFinanceiro pf
JOIN  
    agendamento AS ag ON pf.agendamento_id = ag.id
JOIN 
    profissional pr ON ag.profissionalID = pr.id
JOIN
    clinica cl ON ag.clinicaID = cl.id
WHERE
    ag.pacienteID = 1000011;
```